# Calculating p value using Bootstrap in R for nonparametric test

Tags: r, p-value, nonparametric, bootstrap

Im trying to approximate the p. Value using bootstrap in R by boot function
But in the result is repeated  i.e the values of t0 ….tn are the same so the p value is zero !!!!! I don’t understand why this happened

Comment: Hi. Please provde a replicable example.

Comment: f=function(s){sum((rank(s)+h[sort(sort(s,index=T)$ix,index=T)$ix])*I)}  i want to bootstrap this function ....... can u write for me the command?? by using boot() functions in r